# Dialog functions undefined after wrapping them in a deviceReady event listener

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I've wrote a simple app to test native dialogs. For simplicity, I will only include the code for firing the alert dialog. Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<div id="alert" class="item">
  <h1>Alert</h1>
  <p>Title</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <p>Message</p>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <p>Button label</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <button onclick="alertDiag()" class="submit">GO</button>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
window.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  function alertDiag() {
    var message = document.getElementById("alert").children[4].value;
    var title = document.getElementById("alert").children[2].value;
    var buttonName = document.getElementById("alert").children[6].value;
    function alertCallback() {
      alert("The alert was dismissed");
    }
    navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, title, buttonName);
  }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.nativedialogues" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
  <name>Testing Native Dialogues</name>
  <description>
    An application for testing native dialogues
  </description>
  <author email="example@gmail.com" href="http://www.example.com">
    PhoneGap Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.3.4"/>
</widget>
```

However, since `alertDiag()` is wrapped inside the `deviceReady` event listener, it is undefined when invoked via the button click. In the console I get the following error:

> Cannot get property 'alert' of undefined

What can I do to make the function only available after the device is ready, but at the same time be able to execute it when the button is clicked?

I am using the phonegap cloud build service for packaging the apps, not the local phonegap cli.

Comment: Make sure you've installed `cordova-plugin-dialogs` plugin.

Comment: I am building apps on the cloud, not on my computer. Do I still have to install the plugin?

Comment: put `alertDiag()` method outside of the `onDeviceReady`  and `$(document).ready(function () {..}` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as you may have understood, `deviceready` is an event fired when Cordova has finished loading all plugins for your app. It's just an indication to let you know that if there be a logic that accesses any plugin on page load, then it should ideally go inside the device ready callback.

In your case, the `alertDiag()` is called on user interaction and not on page load. This means you need to define it outside the `deviceready` callback.

```
window.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  // any logic on page load
}

function alertDiag() {
  var message = document.getElementById("alert").children[4].value;
  var title = document.getElementById("alert").children[2].value;
  var buttonName = document.getElementById("alert").children[6].value;

  function alertCallback() {
    alert("The alert was dismissed");
  }
  navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, title, buttonName);
}
```